# Is it possible to define how a type is used in OrderBy criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following types:

```
public class Type1
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Decimal Value { get; get; }
}

public class Type2
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Type1 Type1 { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following function:

```
List<Type2> GetOrderedType2List()    
{
    ...
    return type2List.OrderBy(type2 => type2.Type1).ToList();
}
```

I want instances of `Type2` list to be ordered by their `Type1` property according to `Type1.Value` values. However, I want to write code inside `Type1` that specify how `Type1` is used in `OrderBy` criteria.

Is that possible?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: *However, I want to specify how Type1 is used in OrderBy criteria inside Type1*. I don't understand what that means.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking. Do you mean you want to write the code `within Type1` which determines how to order? If that's correct, you should implement the IComparable interface. (And override equals)

Comment: @AkramShahda still don't get it, could you provide a simple example with input and expected output results?

Comment: @msmolcic I want the Type2 list to be ordered by Type1.Value. But I want that to be specified inside Type1.

Comment: I guess you could write an extension method for your `type2List` named something like `OrderByType1` - it wouldn't per se be in the `Type1` class, but it wouldn't be defined in the `GetOrderedType2List` method either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement IComparable, like so:

```
public class Type1 : IComparable
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Decimal Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        var castObj = obj as Type1;
        if (castObj == null)
            return -1;
        return Value.CompareTo(castObj.Value);
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
var list = new List<Type2> { 
    new Type2 { Type1 = new Type1 { Value = 50 } }, 
    new Type2 { Type1 = new Type1 { Value = 2 } }, 
    new Type2 { Type1 = new Type1 { Value = 100 } }, 
    new Type2 { Type1 = new Type1 { Value = -10 } }
};

list.OrderBy(type2 => type2.Type1);
```

Gives the result:

-10, 2, 50, 100

Alternatively, you can opt to only compare against other Type1 objects (probably the best way to do it), and can do it like this:

```
public class Type1 : IComparable<Type1>
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Decimal Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Type1 obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return -1;
        return Value.CompareTo(obj.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
List<Type2> GetOrderedType2List()    
{
    ...
    return type2List.OrderBy(type2 => type2.Type1.Value).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by value returned from function defined inside your order by. I added some random logic, but you can implement whatever you want:

```
List<Type2> GetOrderedType2List()    
{
    ...
    return type2List.OrderBy(type2 =>
    {
        decimal orderValue;

        if (type2.Type1 == null)
            orderValue = 0;
        else if (type2.Type1.Value < 0)
            orderValue = Math.Abs(type2.Type1.Value);
        else
            orderValue = type2.Type1.Value;

        return orderValue;
    }).ToList();
}
```